# Swift 3 : Negative Int to hexadecimal

Tags: swift, hex

Hy everyone,

I need to transform a Int to its hexadecimal value.
Example : -40 => D8

I have a working method for positive (or unsigned) Int but it doesn't work as expected with negatives. Here's my code.

```
class func encodeHex(data:[Int]) -> String {
    let hexadecimal = data.reduce("") { (string , element) in
        var append = String(element, radix:16 , uppercase : false)
        if append.characters.count == 1 {
            append = "0" + append
        }
       return  string + append
    }
    return hexadecimal
}
```

If I pass -40 I get -28.

Can anyone help ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume from your existing code that all integers are in the range
-128 ... 127. Then this would work:

```
func encodeHex(data:[Int]) -> String {
    return data.map { String(format: "%02hhX", $0) }.joined()
}
```

The `"%02hhX"` format prints the least significant byte of the
given integer in base 16 with 2 digits.

Example:

```
print(encodeHex(data: [40, -40, 127, -128]))
// 28D87F80
```

Comment: This is just perfect, thanks a lot ! And how would you convert the other way around ?

Comment: @LucasAdam: `let num = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8("D8", radix: 16)!)`

Answer (score 4):

`D8` is the last byte of binary representation of `-40`. The remaining three bytes are all `FF`s.

If you are looking for a string that represents only the last byte, you can obtain by first converting your number to unsigned 8-bit integer, and then converting it to hex, like this:

```
let x = UInt8(bitPattern:Int8(data))
let res = String(format:"%02X", x)
```

Comment: Nice, it works fine :) Would you have the opposite aswell ? Like if I get D8, I need to have -40